# Query mongo collection by date only

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have following documents in my collection

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58fe05f29b3b7a313ef74722"),
    "user_id" : "bcd001",
    "age" : 45.0,
    "status" : "A",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-04-24T00:00:00.000Z")
}
...
/* 9 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58fe05f29b3b7a313ef7472a"),
    "user_id" : "bcd020",
    "age" : 50.0,
    "status" : "D",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-04-24T14:04:34.447Z")
}

/* 10 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58fe05f29b3b7a313ef7472b"),
    "user_id" : "bcd021",
    "age" : 51.0,
    "status" : "D",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-04-24T14:04:34.447Z")
}
```

I skipped few documents to cut the question short.

This is my query:

```
db.getCollection('people').find({
    date: {
        $lte: ISODate('2017-04-24'),
        $gte: ISODate('2017-04-24')
    }
});
```

Result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58fe05f29b3b7a313ef74722"),
    "user_id" : "bcd001",
    "age" : 45.0,
    "status" : "A",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-04-24T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

What result I want is:

```
/* 1 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58fe05f29b3b7a313ef74722"),
        "user_id" : "bcd001",
        "age" : 45.0,
        "status" : "A",
        "date" : ISODate("2017-04-24T00:00:00.000Z")
    }

/* 9 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58fe05f29b3b7a313ef7472a"),
        "user_id" : "bcd020",
        "age" : 50.0,
        "status" : "D",
        "date" : ISODate("2017-04-24T14:04:34.447Z")
    }

    /* 10 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58fe05f29b3b7a313ef7472b"),
        "user_id" : "bcd021",
        "age" : 51.0,
        "status" : "D",
        "date" : ISODate("2017-04-24T14:04:34.447Z")
    }
```

I have three docs which contains the date '2017-04-24' but i am getting only one doc in response please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using the aggregation pipeline:

1. In the first stage project the result using $dayOfMonth and all other fields you want in your final output.
2. In second stage use $match to match the day.
3. In the last stage project the result

Read official mongodb documentation related to this, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/

```js
db.getCollection('people').aggregate(
   [
        {
            $project:
            {
                year: { $year: "$date" },
                month: { $month: "$date" },
                day: { $dayOfMonth: "$date" },
                user_id: 1,
                age: 1,
                status: 1,
                date: 1

            }
        },
        {
            $match:
            {
                $and: 
                [
                    {day: 24},
                    {month: 04},
                    {year: 2017}
                ] 

            }
        },
        {
            $project:
            {
                _id:1,user_id: 1,
                age: 1,
                status: 1,
                date: 1
            }
         }
    ]
);
```

Comment: day of the month value repeats every year. So try to include all date values like year, month and day to your match or you can always use `$dateToString` and pass the string value to comparison.

Comment: Ohh yes, that is good pick veeram, i should add month and year in my $match stage. Can you share your answer using $dateToString?

Comment: Something like `db.collection.aggregate([{$project: {ymd: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } }...}},{ $match:{ymd: "2017-04-24"}}....])`

Comment: Just be aware that while this solution may work, it's not going to perform as well as doing the range query. It would not be able to use an index on the date, it will result in a COLLSCAN.

Comment: That is correct statement. None of the aggregation solutions provided here will be able to use indexes. I would recommend testing solutions always no matter in all aspects with your data set.

Comment: Can anyone of you explain in what cases we won't able to use indexes? With or without aggregation?

Comment: @AbdulMoiz there are a number of optimizations that the aggregation framework can do, but it's safe to say that when you are projecting field(s) and then matching against the projected fields, that cannot be optimized and therefore is not going to use an index. It would be best if you could describe your problem more broadly, and why the recommended solution would not work in your case. With any problem there are always many ways that it can be solved, but sometimes not all of them will be optimal.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add a day to your end date, and use `$lt` for the end date. Like this:

```
db.getCollection('people').find({
    date: {
        $lt: ISODate('2017-04-25'),
        $gte: ISODate('2017-04-24')
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there anyway i can query on the basis of date only, ignoring the time part of date time?

Comment: No, it's not possible. This is the preferred approach.

Comment: It is possible, i am answering my own question check if you want and thanks for your answer.

Comment: Well, please share your solution. Don't use $where, not recommended.

Comment: Sorry for being late, i have shared the solution. I am not using $where, can you tell me whats wrong with $where? i heard many times its not recommended. I never came around working with $where, i am new in mongodb.

Comment: @AbdulMoiz This is the recommended solution; it's concise, it gets the right results, and it will not be slow because you are comparing against the actual date stored in the database - so you can make it fast with indexes.

Comment: I tried many of the other approaches shared on StackOverflow... this is the right one

Answer (score 0):

Another answer using the technique @veeram suggested, its shorter as compare to previous answer i am not sure which one is efficient but both are working.

```
db.getCollection('people').aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project: {
                ymd: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } },
                user_id: 1,
                age: 1,
                status: 1,
                date: 1
            }
        },
        { 
            $match:{
                ymd: "2017-04-24"
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                user_id: 1,
                age: 1,
                status: 1,
                date: 1
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. It might get the correct results, but converting the natural date value to a string and then matching that means that you won't benefit from any indexes on the date field - i.e. it will be *very slow* if you have to query on large datasets.